# Prevent Spinner dropdown dismiss when focus changed

Tags: android

I have a dropdown spinner which is showed when click on a button looks like this:

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:visibility="invisible" />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvWall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Here is snippet showing dropdown popup:

```
      findViewById(R.id.btn).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            spinMenu.performClick();                
        }
    });
```

My spinner can show dropdown popup correctly. The problem is my layout has a listview which getting data from web service in background. When data is loading completely, all list items will be showed or refreshed, and the spinner's dropdown popup is dismiss (I even don't touch anything on screen). 
I think the problem is window has changed focus on other view. So how can I prevent it?

**Update**:
Here is my list after load data from background, it's very simple:

```
List<Feed> data = result; 
FeedAdapter adapter = new FeedAdapter (this, data);
ListView lvWall = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvWall);
lvWall.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And data for spinner:

```
 List<String> list = getMenus();
 ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinMenu.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Comment: Could you post the code for `performClick()`? And also, from your Async task where your ListView's content is loaded

Comment: your spinner is hiding or you intentially want to hide it. I did not get what you say . explain

Comment: use android:nextFocusDown="@+id/idyouwannafocus"
    android:nextFocusUp="@+id/et2" attributes to change next

Comment: @ZareAhmer I want to prevent dropdown popup from hiding. I tried your way but still not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a `Spinner` view which you set as invisible with the only purpose of showing the popup menu, but not the Spinner view itself. In that case, the problem is probably related to this snippet in `Spinner.java`, more precisely in `DropdownPopup.show()`:

```
public void show(int textDirection, int textAlignment) {
    ...
    super.show();
    ...

    // Make sure we hide if our anchor goes away.
    // TODO: This might be appropriate to push all the way down to PopupWindow,
    // but it may have other side effects to investigate first. (Text editing handles, etc.)
    final ViewTreeObserver vto = getViewTreeObserver();
    if (vto != null) {
        final OnGlobalLayoutListener layoutListener = new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                if (!Spinner.this.isVisibleToUser()) {
                    dismiss();
                } else {
                    computeContentWidth();

                    ...
```

What does this mean? Basically that the `Spinner` is set up with a `ViewTreeObserver` to be notified whenever a layout pass changes the views in the screen. And **if the Spinner is not visible after that happens**, the popup is dismissed. Loading the `ListView` evidently causes a change in the view hierarchy, and it's being fired when the data arrives from the server.

For general usage this is completely logical: if the `Spinner` is hidden, or it goes off screen, or something like that, it would be reasonable to make the popup go away. However, it's interferring with what you're attempting to do. It would be nice if you could somehow override `isVisibleToUser()`, but unfortunately it's marked as `@hide`, so that's not possible.

Might I suggest a workaround, like setting the `Spinner` visible but really small? Like, with a height of 1px? I believe that should be enough to fool this method.

Another option, and probably a more sensible one, would be to forgo the `Spinner` altogether and use a [`PopupMenu`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html) instead. You can anchor it to the `Button`, load it dynamically, and show it when the button is pressed. The visual effect should be the same.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I'd like to use the Popup Window with custom listview and it worked. Just another question for you: where did you find `DropdownPopup.show()` source code? I try to read on GrepCode but can't find it.

Comment: @R4j It's an inner class inside `Spinner.java`. See https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/Spinner.java around line 1120

Answer (score 1):

If you think the problem is due to the change of focus . You can set it with multiple ways.

first create a focuschangeListener and onfocuschange do whatever you like

```
yourView.setOnFocusChangeListener(testListener);

@Override
      public void onFocusChange(View arg0,
              boolean isFocused) 
      {
          if(isFocused)
           {
              //do your work here
            }
           else
           {
           }
       }
```

And second way to prevent view from focus..

```
<!-- Dummy item to prevent AutoCompleteTextView from receiving focus -->
<LinearLayout
    android:focusable="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="0px"/>

<!-- :nextFocusUp and :nextFocusLeft have been set to the id of this component
     to prevent the dummy from receiving focus again -->
<AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/autotext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:nextFocusUp="@id/autotext" android:nextFocusLeft="@id/autotext"/>
```